# Parsing dictionaries within dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

For example, I have this Python dictionaries within dictionaries, which is returned JSON object:

```
{
    u'BrowseNode': {
        u'Ancestors': {
            u'BrowseNode': {
                u'Ancestors': {
                    u'BrowseNode': {
                        u'Ancestors': {
                            u'BrowseNode': {
                                u'Ancestors': {
                                    u'BrowseNode': {
                                        u'BrowseNodeId': 283155,
                                        u'Name': u'Books'
                                    }
                                },
                                u'BrowseNodeId': 1000,
                                u'IsCategoryRoot': 1,
                                u'Name': u'Subjects'
                            }
                        },
                        u'BrowseNodeId': 75,
                        u'Name': u'Science'
                    }
                },
                u'BrowseNodeId': 14545,
                u'Name': u'Physics'
            }
        },
        u'BrowseNodeId': 226697,
        u'Name': u'Electromagnetism'
    }
}
```

and I want to get "Name" key values, but leaving Python object as is (without converting it or similar)

Output should be like this:

```
Books, Subjects, Science, Physics, Electromagnetism
```

Thanks

Comment: What format do you want the 'Name' values returned in? What have you tried? What did it do?

Comment: I want string format as is. I've tried many crazy combinations without success, so I thought to ask for expert help. Thanks

Comment: So you want to turn that into a list of Names? Can you be a little more specific? Show exactly what the output should be.

Comment: Also are you controlling that output? That looks extremely non-standard and practically unparsable. Do you know how deep the nesting is beforehand?

Comment: Also I started with JSON thou I could have XML object instead and use lxml, but don't want to rewrite everything now, as script is working fine to this point.

Comment: For those asking about the data structure, it looks at first glance like it might come from Amazon -- they use things called "BrowseNodes" and it is about books...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this also works for the given data and it's not recursive:

```
def collect_names( node ):
    names = []
    while True:
        names.append(node[u'Name'])
        try:
            # deeper node
            node = node[u'Ancestors'][u'BrowseNode']
        except KeyError:
            # we are done, no ancestors 
            return names[::-1]

print collect_names(data[u'BrowseNode'])
# >> [u'Books', u'Subjects', u'Science', u'Physics', u'Electromagnetism']
```

Comment: Thanks. Your function is working correct for this problem as I just tested. FYI, I returned to lxml module and parsed XML response instead this nested JSON styled dict. JSON was suggested by the author of bottlenose (Amazon API) module which I blindly followed to my unfortune

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_name(d):
    name = d.get('Name')
    if name:
        print name
    ancestors = d.get('Ancestors')
    if ancestors:
        print_name(ancestors)
```

Recursively print name attributes...

Comment: Though I should add that your data structure looks messy.  Without knowing what it is used for, I can't recommend an alternative structure.

Comment: This function prints only the last name: 'Electromagnetism'

Comment: You got the order "wrong" (OP's example output is depth-first, yours is breadth-first) - but otherwise good solution. The conditions should read `if x is not None:` though.

Answer (score 1):

Classical use case for [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

From the top of my head:

1. Write a function which takes a dictionary and a list as its parameters
2. Inside the function iterate over all the dictionary's keys
3. If the key is "Name" then add the value to the list
4. If not, and the type value of the key is a dictionary, call the function and pass this dictionary and the list with the names
5. At the end of the function simply return the dictionary

To get the stuff call `names = func(baseDict, [])`.